# How to make TextToSpeech speak faster?

Tags: java, android, queue, text-to-speech

I am developing a metronome app with `TextToSpeech`. And I kinda made a `Metronome` class to handle all of this stuff (This is the full code. But I'll tell you where to focus on later):

```
public class Metronome {
    private static final int DEFAULT_BPM = 115;
    private Timer timer;
    private int tempo;
    private int maxBeats;
    private int currentBeat;
    private BeatDivider inBeat;
    private BeatType beatType;

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    public void setMaxBeats(int maxBeats) {
        this.maxBeats = maxBeats;
    }

    public void setTempo (int tempo) {
        timer.setInterval (getMillisecondsFromBpm (tempo, beatType));
        this.tempo = tempo;
    }

    public void setBeatType (BeatType type) {
        beatType = type;
        setTempo (tempo);
    }

    public int getMaxBeats() {
        return maxBeats;
    }

    public BeatDivider getInBeat() {
        return inBeat;
    }

    public int getTempo () {
        return tempo;
    }

    public void reset () {
        if (!timer.isPaused ())
            throw new IllegalStateException ("Timer cannot be running when reset");

        inBeat = BeatDivider.ON_BEAT;
        currentBeat = 1;
    }

    public void start () {
        timer.startTimer ();
    }

    public void stop () {
        timer.stopTimer ();
        reset ();
    }

    public boolean isRunning () {
        return !timer.isPaused ();
    }

    public Metronome (Context c) {
        timer = new Timer (new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                beep ();
                increment ();
            }
        }, getMillisecondsFromBpm (DEFAULT_BPM, BeatType.QUARTER), false);
        tts = new TextToSpeech (c, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener () {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {

            }
        });
        tts.setSpeechRate (2);
        setBeatType (BeatType.QUARTER);
        setMaxBeats (4);
        setTempo (DEFAULT_BPM);
    }

    private int getMillisecondsFromBpm (int bpm, BeatType type) {
        int ms = (int)Math.pow (bpm / 60.0, -1) * 1000;

        switch (type) {
            case QUARTER:
                return ms;
            case EIGHTH:
                return ms / 2;
            case SIXTEENTH:
                return ms / 4;
        }

        return ms;
    }

    private void increment () {
        if (beatType == BeatType.QUARTER) {
            incrementBeat ();
        } else if (beatType == BeatType.EIGHTH) {
            incrementEighth ();
        } else if (beatType == BeatType.SIXTEENTH) {
            incrementSixteenth ();
        }
    }

    private void incrementSixteenth() {
        switch (inBeat) {
            case E:
                inBeat = BeatDivider.AND;
                break;
            case A:
                inBeat = BeatDivider.ON_BEAT;
                incrementBeat ();
                break;
            case ON_BEAT:
                inBeat = BeatDivider.E;
                break;
            case AND:
                inBeat = BeatDivider.A;
        }
    }

    private void incrementEighth() {
        switch (inBeat) {
            case E:
            case ON_BEAT:
                inBeat = BeatDivider.AND;
                break;
            case A:
            case AND:
                inBeat = BeatDivider.ON_BEAT;
                incrementBeat ();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void incrementBeat() {
        inBeat = BeatDivider.ON_BEAT;
        if (currentBeat < maxBeats) {
            currentBeat++;
        } else {
            currentBeat = 1;
        }
    }

    private void beep () {
        tts.speak (getBeatString (), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    private String getBeatString () {
        switch (inBeat) {
            case ON_BEAT:
                default:
                return Integer.toString (currentBeat);
            case E:
                return "e";
            case AND:
                return "and";
            case A:
                return "Ah";
        }
    }

    public enum BeatDivider {
        ON_BEAT,
        E,
        AND,
        A
    }

    public enum BeatType {
        QUARTER,
        EIGHTH,
        SIXTEENTH
    }
}
```

Explanation:

The `Timer` class just does what it says. It's my custom implementation. There should be no problems there. The idea is, the user can set the tempo (`tempo`), the time signature (`maxBeats`) and the type of notes (`BeatType`). With quater notes it goes like 1 2 3 4 and with eighth notes it goes like 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and so on. The `TextToSpeech` will speak those words out.

The problem:

When I increase the bpm to 80 or 90 something, the tts doesn't speak! And somehow when I decrease the bpm, it goes like 1 3 1 3 1 3. The reason is that it speaks too slowly.

My attempts to solve it:

Because I think it speaks to slowly, I increased the speech rate to 4. But the same thing happened again! Then I tried to use `QUEUE_ADD` instead of `QUEUE_FLUSH`. When I increased the bpm from 60 to 150, tts still spoke with the initial speed! Then I tried to press the stop button, but after that, tts still kept speaking and speaking and speaking until I `finish()` the activity!

I really want to know how can this be solved. I guess reducing the time taken between speeches is what I need to do. But how? Or if I replace tts with a "beep" sound and use `MediaPlayer`, will this occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change speed by tts.setPitch(1); and tts.setSpeechRate(2);